# Create VM Azure REST API in Java - The specified deployment slot Production is occupied

Tags: rest, azure, virtual-machine

I got this error `The specified deployment slot Production is occupied` when I try to create a VM with REST API.

In my XML, I have `<DeploymentSlot>Production</DeploymentSlot>` but I can't find any information for resolving this issue.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please see if there's a VM deployment already running in the production slot. If that's the case, then you can't create another deployment there. The deployment slot needs to be empty for create deployment operation to succeed.

Comment: Yes there is already one ! I need to use this request : `https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deployments` but where can I find the `<cloudservice-name>` ?

Comment: This is something you would have created in the portal or you could create a cloud service in your subscription using `Create Cloud Service`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg441304.aspx.

Comment: Yes that's what I did : first create a cloud service and then a VM. Thanks for your help Gaurav.